# html forms to django

Tags: python, html, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python/django adder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423687/python-django-adder)

I am new to django and tryed to make a site that takes my number (inputted from an  of html) and add/ subtract it to an other.

So i tryed this in views.py:

```
def calc(request):
    try:     
        i1 = int(request.GET['i1'])
        i2 = int(request.GET['i2'])
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        raise Http404()
    u = i2 + i1
    return ("answer.html", u)
```

i also showed this to some other people and they told me to make a 'link/bond' to the html, how can i make such a link without using a database?

edit: I am very sorry guys, I started to learn django from The Djangobook and they didn't explain it as clearly as you guys or the documentation, my sincere apologies

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense: particularly the last lines. Please revise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to answer this simply so we can be done with this question, which was also posted yesterday. I'm not trying to be rude here, but you really need to do some research, read some tutorials, etc, *before* asking a question that doesn't really make a whole lot of sense. I'm sticking the save logic of the form in the view so you can see what's going on.

```
#forms.py
from django import forms

class AdditionForm(forms.Form):
    first_number = forms.IntegerField()
    second_number = forms.IntegerField()


#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

from [your_app].forms imort AdditionForm

def calc(request):
    form = AdditionForm(request.POST or None)
    answer = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            first_number = form.cleaned_data.get('first_number', 0)
            second_number = form.cleaned_data.get('second_number', 0)
            answer = first_number + second_number
    return render(request, 'some-file.html', {'form' : form, 'answer' : answer})


#some-file.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <fieldset>
                <ol>
                    {{ form.as_ul }}
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Add the Numbers" />
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        {% if answer %}
        <p>Your answer was: {{ answer }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading django tutorial, It cleary and simply explains how to do exactly what you want to in more detail then could be provided to you here.  The link is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/